# Two-way sync of text-field with server - fast typing

Tags: graphql, subscription

I'm using a graphql mutation and a subscription to have an input sync bidirectionally with a server: When the user inputs data, on every keyup the mutation is triggered, and when data on the server changes, the input is updated. So, when a keyup occurs, the changed text is sent to the server and updated there, and because of the subscription, the now changed data on the server is sent to the textfield (which is unnecessary because they both contain the same data)

Now when the user is typing quickly and inputs, let's say an `a` and then a `b` almost simultaneously, the `a` and then immediately the `b` is sent to the server, which leads to the server only having the `b` in the end; therefore, the server updates the client where it also only contains a `b` and not `ab`, as intended.

Is there an easy mechanism/already existing algorithm that can prevent this?

Answer (score 0):

From your description of the value that is getting to the server, there is probably a debounce mechanism on your client input. Assuming that sending back the value from the server immediately is a desired behaviour, I propose that you sent the entire input value string, so that instead of sending just `a` then `b`, you send `ab`
you would have to overwrite the entire server value on every new request, but it should work